# What is Community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I'm seeing posts show up that are labeled "community wiki."  What are these? It's not a tag and I can't list them all.  Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[What are Community Wikis?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

You make a wiki by checking the box at bottom right, when editing a Q/A. This does several things.

- It makes the question owned by the Community, so anyone (above a certain rep) can edit them.
- You neither gain nor lose reputation based on votes.

It's intended for Questions that are **not** really good single-Answer type questions - if they are subjective, or have no single right answer ("what's a good gamedev book"), so you couldn't checkmark one as best.

**Update** - you can **no longer** make a Question into a wiki (unless you're a moderator).

- [Wiki Button - Missing, presumed dead - film at 11:00](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action)

Comment: I definitely need to improve the /faq in this area..

Comment: Also, being able to categorize and look at things that are all "community wiki" topics would be nice (as in reality, they tend to make up the FAQ for a given subject).

Comment: Great, I finally understand what they are.  Instead of a faq, you should just be able to click on the "Community Wiki" label to get a quick description of it.

Comment: How much reputation do I need to turn a question into a community wiki? Someone suggested I should do that but I can't really find that one checkbox!

Comment: @Edmundito, if you mean your *own* Question, there's no rep requirement - just *edit* it, and look for a checkbox at the bottom right. If you mean other questions, I'm not sure how much rep - might be 2K, or more, the FAQ isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

These questions on Meta Stack Overflow seem relevant:

- [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740)
- [When to mark the ‘community wiki’ checkbox on a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question)